# Can't access Kubernetes load balancer service (EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm having trouble accessing my Kubernetes service of type Load Balancer with the external IP and port listed by kubectl. When running `curl <external-ip>:<port>` I receive an empty response.
I ran into the issue when trying to [install](https://docs.onap.org/projects/onap-oom/en/latest/sections/guides/infra_guides/oom_base_config_setup.html#oom-base-setup-guide) and [deploy](https://docs.onap.org/projects/onap-oom/en/latest/sections/guides/deployment_guides/oom_helm_release_repo_deploy.html) ONAP on an EKS cluster.
I've checked that the ports in my service and pod are configured correctly. I've also made sure that the listener and health check in my load balancer are configured correctly. I've also made sure that the security groups for my load balancer and ec2 instances are configured correctly.
However none of my ec2 instances are passing the health check, it seems that the pod is not exposing the web server on the correct port.

Here's the yaml for the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: dev-portal
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: onap
      msb.onap.org/service-info: '[ { "serviceName": "portal", "version": "v2", "url":
        "/", "protocol": "REST" "port": "8989", "visualRange":"1" } ]'
    creationTimestamp: "2023-04-07T16:10:48Z"
    finalizers:
    - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
    labels:
      app: portal-app
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      chart: portal-app-12.0.0
      heritage: Helm
      release: dev
    name: portal-app
    namespace: onap
    resourceVersion: "265274"
    uid: 2954dab3-c55b-440d-8fc8-465eabde1342
  spec:
    allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
    clusterIP: 10.100.158.119
    clusterIPs:
    - 10.100.158.119
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
    ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
    ports:
    - name: portal-app4
      nodePort: 30225
      port: 8443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8443
    selector:
      app: portal-app
      release: dev
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: LoadBalancer
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - hostname: a2954dab3c55b440d8fc8465eabde134-1728302376.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

and here's the yaml for the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2023-04-07T16:10:48Z"
    generateName: dev-portal-app-766746f559-
    labels:
      app: portal-app
      pod-template-hash: 766746f559
      release: dev
    name: dev-portal-app-766746f559-8qdq4
    namespace: onap
    ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: ReplicaSet
      name: dev-portal-app-766746f559
      uid: 7de948a4-55b0-4db4-8c59-f7013b09d842
    resourceVersion: "269232"
    uid: f4a4561b-0be8-46d1-9b2c-f15954159f7a
  spec:
    containers:
    - args:
      - /start-apache-tomcat.sh -i "" -n "" -b /usr/local/tomcat
      command:
      - bash
      - -c
      image: nexus3.onap.org:10001/onap/portal-app:3.4.2
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        tcpSocket:
          port: 8080
        timeoutSeconds: 1
      name: portal-app
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 8005
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 8009
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 8443
        protocol: TCP
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        tcpSocket:
          port: 8080
        timeoutSeconds: 1
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /etc/localtime
        name: localtime
        readOnly: true
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/fusion/conf/fusion.properties
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: fusion.properties
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/classes/openid-connect.properties
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: openid-connect.properties
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/conf/system.properties
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: system.properties
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/classes/portal.properties
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: portal.properties
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/classes/key.properties
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: key.properties
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/classes/music.properties
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: music.properties
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: logback.xml
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: server.xml
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ONAPPORTAL/WEB-INF/web.xml
        name: properties-onapportal
        subPath: web.xml
      - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
        name: properties-onapportal
      - mountPath: /var/log/onap
        name: var-log-onap
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: kube-api-access-rq4n5
        readOnly: true
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    enableServiceLinks: true
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: onap-docker-registry-key
    initContainers:
    - args:
      - --job-name
      - dev-portal-db-config
      command:
      - /app/ready.py
      env:
      - name: NAMESPACE
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      image: nexus3.onap.org:10001/onap/oom/readiness:3.0.1
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: portal-app-job-completion
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: kube-api-access-rq4n5
        readOnly: true
    - args:
      - -c
      - |
        cd /config-input && \
        for PFILE in `ls -1 *.xml`
        do
          cp ${PFILE} /config
          chmod 0755 /config/${PFILE}
        done
        cd /config-input && \
        for PFILE in `ls -1 *.properties`
        do
          envsubst <${PFILE} >/config/${PFILE}
          chmod 0755 /config/${PFILE}
        done
      command:
      - sh
      env:
      - name: CASSA_USER
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: login
            name: dev-portal-cass-creds
      - name: CASSA_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: password
            name: dev-portal-cass-creds
      - name: CIPHER_ENC_KEY
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: password
            name: dev-portal-app-cipher-enc-key
      - name: PORTAL_DB_USER
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: login
            name: dev-portal-backend-creds
      - name: PORTAL_DB_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: password
            name: dev-portal-backend-creds
      image: docker.io/dibi/envsubst:1
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: portal-app-portal-config
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /config-input
        name: properties-onapportal-scrubbed
      - mountPath: /config
        name: properties-onapportal
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: kube-api-access-rq4n5
        readOnly: true
    nodeName: ip-172-31-21-183.us-west-1.compute.internal
    preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
    priority: 0
    restartPolicy: Always
    schedulerName: default-scheduler
    securityContext: {}
    serviceAccount: dev-portal-app-read
    serviceAccountName: dev-portal-app-read
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    tolerations:
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /etc/localtime
        type: ""
      name: localtime
    - emptyDir:
        medium: Memory
      name: properties-onapportal
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 493
        name: dev-portal-app-onapportal
      name: properties-onapportal-scrubbed
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: var-log-onap
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: portal-tomcat-logs
    - name: kube-api-access-rq4n5
      projected:
        defaultMode: 420
        sources:
        - serviceAccountToken:
            expirationSeconds: 3607
            path: token
        - configMap:
            items:
            - key: ca.crt
              path: ca.crt
            name: kube-root-ca.crt
        - downwardAPI:
            items:
            - fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              path: namespace
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2023-04-07T16:19:31Z"
      status: "True"
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2023-04-07T16:19:58Z"
      status: "True"
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2023-04-07T16:19:58Z"
      status: "True"
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2023-04-07T16:10:48Z"
      status: "True"
      type: PodScheduled
    containerStatuses:
    - containerID: containerd://67b837b557a981522ad5250dc095f817cfe8a90d07ec4470768417507daa4eb2
      image: nexus3.onap.org:10001/onap/portal-app:3.4.2
      imageID: nexus3.onap.org:10001/onap/portal-app@sha256:e9f2a12f614d7d686c6fac443cc1268c7deee82811638da82c70ac97856611f7
      lastState: {}
      name: portal-app
      ready: true
      restartCount: 0
      started: true
      state:
        running:
          startedAt: "2023-04-07T16:19:41Z"
    hostIP: 172.31.21.183
    initContainerStatuses:
    - containerID: containerd://a6ebe68a57b3c6dbcd07647d6150888371501bb5de27289ac61650fbbb30162e
      image: nexus3.onap.org:10001/onap/oom/readiness:3.0.1
      imageID: nexus3.onap.org:10001/onap/oom/readiness@sha256:317c8a361ae73750f4d4a1b682c42b73de39083f73228dede31fd68b16c089db
      lastState: {}
      name: portal-app-job-completion
      ready: true
      restartCount: 0
      state:
        terminated:
          containerID: containerd://a6ebe68a57b3c6dbcd07647d6150888371501bb5de27289ac61650fbbb30162e
          exitCode: 0
          finishedAt: "2023-04-07T16:19:25Z"
          reason: Completed
          startedAt: "2023-04-07T16:10:49Z"
    - containerID: containerd://099bcc0dc0b8c45415304dbc8a116987242aee49fead9c9600d0fe8c6d47a746
      image: docker.io/dibi/envsubst:1
      imageID: docker.io/dibi/envsubst@sha256:6f1938ec2114e98406b9dcc638929fcbe68add3d94eb8629e0cbed03b72f09f8
      lastState: {}
      name: portal-app-portal-config
      ready: true
      restartCount: 0
      state:
        terminated:
          containerID: containerd://099bcc0dc0b8c45415304dbc8a116987242aee49fead9c9600d0fe8c6d47a746
          exitCode: 0
          finishedAt: "2023-04-07T16:19:30Z"
          reason: Completed
          startedAt: "2023-04-07T16:19:30Z"
    phase: Running
    podIP: 172.31.24.222
    podIPs:
    - ip: 172.31.24.222
    qosClass: BestEffort
    startTime: "2023-04-07T16:10:48Z"
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

I'm expecting to get a response from the web server, but right now am getting an empty response. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to get a response from the web server by using curl, but got an empty response.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to service using the hostIP:nodeport? Looks like you're creating a service of type:NodePort.
```
  spec:
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: NodePort
```

Comment: @JeremyCowan That doesn't seem to work. That hostIP is the private IP of the node (ec2 instance) running the pod for the service. But it doesn't seem to be serving the anything on that port.

Comment: Also @JeremyCowan I included the yaml for the wrong service, I have updated the original question.

Comment: Try kubectl port forward. If it doesn’t work there’s something wrong with your service.